# Why is the Bluetooth UI different on two Windows 7 systems?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, bluetooth, x86

I have two Windows 7 systems, one is Windows 7 x86, the other is Windows 7 x64.

When my BT device connect to my Windows 7 x86 system, it has a nice UI with all the functions my device support;

When my BT device connect to my Windows 7 x64 system, it only has a dummy device properties setting dialog. some tabs at the top, and the 'ok', 'cancel' and 'apply' buttons at the bottom :(

I want to know if this problem is caused by the BT dongle? Or the OS? or the dongle driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is the Device Stage view within the Devices and Printers dialog.  The information provided is completley driver dependent.  It would seem your BT device vendor has put more effort into their x86 vs x64 driver package.

[Windows Team Blog entry regarding Deivce Stage](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/windowsexperience/archive/2009/01/08/device-stage-a-new-way-of-interacting-with-devices-in-windows-7.aspx)